# Max value index of multidimentional array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, max

I need to find the max value and index of a multi-dimentional array in C++, for example if I have the array `arr` which has 4 dimentions:
`int r[10][10][10][10]` with random values in it, I need to find a solution in the form:

> max_value : 104
>
> max_valu_index : (3,4,8,2)

Basically I am trying to construct a 3D Hough Transform accumulator. Many Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply walking the array with 3 nested loops ?

Comment: So go ahead and do it.

Comment: have you ever heard of `loop` ?

Comment: One trick here is to remember these arrays are stored linearly so only 1 loop is needed, use a ptr and then *ptr++ till the end, then modulo to get the indices

Comment: @QuentinUK That's what I would do.  Much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, @QuentinUK im still new to c++, did not understand how to use modulo with pointer. can you eleborate please? thanks

Comment: When you have the ptr for the max value, subtract from this the ptr for the first, to get the index. 0 to 9999 an integer. This has to be split into 4. So index%10 gets one, (index/10)%10 gets the next etc

Answer (score 2):

```
int max = r [0][0][0][0];
int ma = 0, mb = 0, mc = 0, md = 0;

for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
            for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++)
            { 
                if (r [a][b][c][d] > max)
                {
                    max = r [a][b][c][d];
                    ma = a;
                    mb = b;
                    mc = c;
                    md = d;
                }
            }

printf ("max_value : %d max_value_index : (%d, %d, %d, %d)", max, ma, mb, mc, md);
```

Comment: I guess by `sprintf` you meant `printf` since there is no destination string :)